# Gaps and Islands Months only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I am working with a data set of clients and their date records. I am trying to apply a gaps and island problem only using MONTHS,( currently var char 'YYYYMM'). I need to take individual records and group by gaps in months(irregardless of year). I cant figure out how to go from:

[image: Current]

```
drop table RUNNING_LOG;

create table running_log ( 
  run_date          date not null,  
  time_in_seconds   int  not null, 
  distance_in_miles int  not null,
  SERV_YRMO         VARCHAR2(6)
);

insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-01', 420, 1,'201801');  
insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-02', 2400, 5,'201801');  
insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-03', 2430, 5,'201801');  
insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-06', 2350, 5,'201801');  
insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-07', 410, 1,'201802');  
insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-10', 400, 1,'201802');  
insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-13', 2300, 5,'201802');  
insert into running_log values (date'2018-12-31', 425, 1,'201803');  
insert into running_log values (date'2019-01-01', 422, 1,'201901');  
insert into running_log values (date'2019-01-06', 2350, 5,'201901');  
insert into running_log values (date'2019-02-07', 410, 1,'201902');  
insert into running_log values (date'2019-02-10', 400, 1,'201902');  
insert into running_log values (date'2019-02-13', 2300, 5,'201902');  
insert into running_log values (date'2019-03-14', 425, 1,'201903');  
insert into running_log values (date'2019-03-15', 422, 1,'201903');
insert into running_log values (date'2020-03-01', 425, 1,'202003');  
insert into running_log values (date'2021-03-31', 422, 1,'202103');   

commit;  

select * from running_log;
```

To: [image: Final Result]

Comment: What Oracle version? `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` is probably the most efficient way, but it only exists since Oracle 12.1. Otherwise the tabibitosan method is probably your best bet. I can show you either solution (or both), but first tell us your Oracle version.

Comment: Note: Immediately after you drop the table and create it again from scratch, there is no need to truncate it.

Comment: 11g sadly. wouldnt mind learning both ways.

Comment: Is your arithmetic wrong? In the INSERT statements the first seven rows are for Jan and Feb 2018, and the sum of distances is 23, not 16.

Comment: Err... Also, your inserts are wrong. Look at row 8:  `(date'2018-12-31', 425, 1,'201803'); `  If the date is 31 December 2018, then the year-month is not 201803. Do you really have that column there? It should not exist - it is calculated from the date column. In my solution I will drop the YRMO column and work only off of the date column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is uses `dense_rank()` and truncating dates to months:

```
select to_char(min(run_date), 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(max(run_date), 'YYYY-MM'), sum(distance)
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by trunc(run_date, 'Month')) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by trunc(run_date, 'Month') - seqnum * interval '1' month
order by min(run_date);
```

Comment: Ok i tweaked this aspect. Can interval 1 be changed to any gap length like only break after a 2 month window?

Comment: Besides assorted typos and other mistakes (in the subquery, the table referenced in the FROM clause should be `RUNNING_LOG`, not `T`; in the outer `SELECT`, the closing parenthesis for the second `MAX(...)` is in the wrong place; the OP's column name is `DISTANCE_IN_MILES`, and the `DISTANCE` in your code is in fact an Oracle reserved word, etc.), there is a more serious mistake, which makes the query return an error... the `TRUNC` in `ORDER BY` should also be `TRUNC(....., 'Month')`. You are missing the second argument.

Comment: So, question:  The OP posted perfectly workable `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. So - why not test what you post, before you post it?

Comment: @Tinkinc . . . If you want something like that, an alternative approach using `lag()` is probably simpler.

Comment: @mathguy  Would happen to know how I can create only when there is a total of 4 month gap in months? to break the link only when 4 months is no running detail.

Comment: @Tinkinc - your last question is not very clear, but if I understand it correctly, then it is quite different from the original one. You may do better to ask it as a separate question, rather than tuck it in as a comment to an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below uses the tabibitosan method to create the groups. If you are not familiar with this concept, google for it - you will find many good write-ups on it. (Sometimes also called the "fixed differences" method.) The heart of the method is the creation of groups in the subquery; select the subquery and run it by itself, without the outer query, to see what it does. Look particularly at the GRP column in the subquery; if you ask yourself HOW it does that, that's where you need to read about the method.

As I explained in a Comment under your question, the `SERV_YRMO` column is not needed (if it is computed from the `RUN_DATE` value anyway), and in fact your `INSERT` statements have errors in that column. The solution below only uses `RUN_DATE` - you may as well drop the `SERV_YRMO` column, which will only cause trouble.

Note also that, as I pointed out in another Comment under your question, your arithmetic seems wrong. My output is different from yours, for that reason.

```
select to_char(min(run_date), 'yyyymm') as min_yrmo,
       to_char(max(run_date), 'yyyymm') as max_yrmo,
       sum(distance_in_miles)           as total_distance
from   (
         select rl.*, 
                add_months( trunc(run_date, 'mm'), 
                            -dense_rank() over (order by trunc(run_date, 'mm'))
                          ) as grp
         from   running_log rl
       )
group  by grp
order  by min_yrmo
;

MIN_YRMO MAX_YRMO TOTAL_DISTANCE
-------- -------- --------------
201801   201802               23
201812   201903               16
202003   202003                1
202103   202103                1
```

**EDIT**

The OP's version is 11 of some description. Still, for readers who may have the same question and have Oracle version 12.1 or higher, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` can be used for a more efficient solution. It looks like this:

```
select *
from   running_log
match_recognize(
  order    by run_date
  measures to_char(first(run_date), 'yyyymm') as min_yrmo,
           to_char(last (run_date), 'yyyymm') as max_yrmo,
           sum(distance_in_miles)             as total_distance
  pattern  ( a b* )
  define   b as run_date < add_months(trunc(prev(run_date), 'mm'), 2)
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below SQL which use tabibitosan method of finding gap. resut consider count=1 as lake count >1 as Island

```
select min(run_date), MAX(run_date), count(grp), decode (count(grp),1,'LAKE','ISLAND')
from (
select run_date, run_date - rownum as grp 
from omc.running_log 
order by RUN_DATE
)
group by grp ;
```

[image]